# Help me to convince my son that Santa Claus exists, scientifically

Tags: santa-claus

I'm afraid that this might be off-topic, but here is my problem: As Christmas is coming, my son asks me lot of questions about Santa. I try to answer all his questions, but sometimes, I don't have any good answer. My son loves science, and I try to teach him critical thinking and skepticism, so I want a rational answer instead of "it's magic". I know this community is really good at creating out of the box answers, so I try my luck.

1. How can Santa have enough time to deliver toys to everyone?
2. How can Santa answer all the children? Does he know all the languages in the world?
3. How will Santa leave presents if there is no chimney?
4. How can Santa know where to deliver, if we are not at home, and instead at grandparents' house?
5. How can he eat all stuff that we offer him? (I don't know if it's the same everywhere, but we offer some food to Santa during the night, and in the morning, the food has disappeared.)

Comment: "i try to teach him critical thinking and skepticism" and "I'm trying to find the best lies to tell my son about Santa Claus" aren't very compatible goals...

Comment: 1) Santa isn't one person, it's like a company and he is the CEO, so he has a lot of employes (elves) that deliver gifts. 2) In the past, Santa use elves to help him with translations, now he use a translation software. 3) Easy, thieves are able to open doors even without keys, santa too. 3) Or Santa hack every cellphone an use the GPS, or Santa made a contract with all the hospitals and when we born the docto put us a GPS chip for Santa use. 5) He can't eat everything, he allow his elves to eat the food, otherwise he would die by a cardiac arrest...

Comment: Tell him Santa is an alien with super advance technology.

Comment: @Azuaron that's why i need as scientifacl answer as possible, but i know it won't last. The thing is, I don't want to say them explicitely that santa don't exist, but prefer that they understand it by themselves, as late as possible, even if it will comme lot sooner than other kids. Yes, I want them to have scientifical thinking, but they are also children, so i don't want to spoil christmas

Comment: https://sploid.gizmodo.com/can-santa-claus-exist-a-scientific-debate-1669957032 or tell him Santa is Amazon with a red hat....

Comment: When you're in a hole, stop digging?

Comment: "Any sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic." Arthur C. Clarke.

Comment: @kexedu If he is already asking those questions, there is no reason to keep lying to him. Just tell him to not spoil it for everyone because the holiday isn't really about Santa but all the traditions are just an excuse for people to celebrate something and to make life a little bit more interesting for everyone.

Comment: @kexedu Telling your child "There is no Santa." emphatically does *not* spoil Christmas. We make sure that our children know the truth, that they always have, and their Christmas is not spoiled.

Comment: @kexedu You have a very low opinion of your child's imaginative abilities if you think the knowledge that Santa doesn't exist is going to "spoil" anything. And successfully using scientific explanations for Santa is likely to disillusion your son from science when he learns Santa _isn't_ real and you tricked him with science.

Comment: You're coming at it the wrong way. Use the Socratic method. If he expresses doubt about Santa Claus, ask him why and get him to explain his reasons. If he gives a bad reason ("Because someone said so on TV and people on TV are always right"), point it out that it's not a valid argument--and why--against Santa Claus. If he gives a legitimate reason ("Reindeer can't fly") then get him to justify it, gently probing why he thinks that. Depending on how old he is, he'll probably get annoyed at some point and either call you out or get bored and leave. But don't lie.

Comment: Why is this question held as too broad? It sounds less broad than the question about "Santa's broke; how much does it cost to pay for a year of Santa's activities" that was recently asked and received much positive attention. And this question has one good answer, though I think we could do better.

Comment: @kexedu I just asked on meta about why this was put on hold as "too broad" and what should be done about it. The only feedback so far is that sphennings thinks you should ask this as multiple questions, one for each sub-question you asked.

Comment: The mentioned [meta] question is [Is “Convince son of Santa scientifically” too broad?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5714/29)

Comment: The main problem I see with _any_ of the Santa questions we inevitably get this time of year are that _they are rarely actually about Worldbuilding_. They're more like Q&A "games" that people want to play, which, IMO, don't really have a place here and detract from the usefulness of the SE. This one, while actually about Worldbuilding, the world being built is "the real world, but with lies so I can gaslight my son", and I **really** don't feel comfortable supporting _gaslighting_ or that it's something SE should encourage.

Comment: The real answer I heard from a presentor was “congratulates! You solved the puzzle.  Now don't spoil it for little brother…”

Comment: If you're child is asking these questions he/she is well beyond believing in Santa as a person and is ready to believe in Santa as a symbol.  Allow me to quote from Terry Pratchett's *Hogfather,* "Take the universe and grind it down to the finest powder and sieve it through the finest sieve and then show me one atom of justice, one molecule of mercy. And yet you act as if there is some ideal order in the world, as if there is some...some rightness in the universe by which it may be judged."  Believing in Santa teaches us how to believe in a better world.

Answer (score 1):

First, science will show it is impossible.  You're looking for an explination which will satisfy the doubts.

**Question:** How can Santa have enough time to deliver toys to everyone?

**Answer:**  First, let us adjust the scope.  Santa only delivers toys to those children who celebrate Christmas.  Many countries don't celebrate Christmas.See examples [here](https://greenglobaltravel.com/countries-that-dont-celebrate-christmas/).  Second, Santa has a full 24 hours of darkness.  Additionally, we know that time is not fixed.  The passage of [time is relative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_dilation) to speed and mass.  Perhaps Santa's work takes weeks but is compressed from our frame of reference to one night.

**Question:**  How can Santa answer all the children? Does he know all the languages in the world?

**Answer:**  What most people don't realize is that Santa is a [Hyperpolyglot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyglotism).  He has an uncanny ability to learn languages.  [There are documented cases](http://www.onlinecollegecourses.com/2012/07/29/10-most-impressive-polyglots-in-world-history/) of people speaking more than 50 languages.  Since he so long lived, he has mastered many.  For those he doesn't know, he has a cadre of Elvin translators to assist him.  It is actually the Elves who construct the naughty and nice list for him, distilling the intelligence reports from all the Shelf-Elves and other informants (like the family pets and school administrators.)  Once again, not every language group celebrates Christmas.  While there are almost [7,000 languages](http://www.education.rec.ri.cmu.edu/fire/naclo/pages/Ling/Fact/num-languages.html), 94% of the world population speaks around 400 or fewer.

**Question:**  How will Santa leave presents if there is no chimney?

**Answer:** Santa employes several techniques.  First, he has a magic key.  It operates like a [skeleton key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skeleton_key).  He has also been known to use a window.  Since the size of Santa seems to change (from tiny Elf in the night before Christmas to human-sized in every Department store), Santa may be able to alter his size to fit under doorjambs.

**Question:**  How can Santa know where to deliver, if we are not at home, and instead at grandparents' house?

**Answer:** Because parents leave a note for Santa telling him where you are.  It works like the [postal services mail forwarding servcie](https://www.usps.com/manage/forward.htm).

**Question:**  How can he eat all stuff that we offer him? (I don't know if it's the same everywhere, but we offer some food to Santa during the night, and in the morning, the food has disappeared.)

**Answer:**  With time dilation, we don't know exactly how long it might take Santa to deliver all those presents.  However, he does work very quickly and works up an appetite.  Santa has been known to leave a cookie or two for dad or mom to eat if his belly was full at the time.

Comment: Exactly how I would approach it. Magic being interpreted as misunderstood science helps foster curiosity. Skeleton key that works on any lock is a good one.

Comment: Answer questions as they arise, informally,  understanding that there will come a day when he'll realize the truth. My daughter figured it out by the wrapping paper.

Answer (score 0):

- Earth rotates, and the night is quite long during winter, so he has more time than you think. Plus, Santa doesn't have to deliver presentations to ALL children: some are bad, so now present for them. In Spain, children have present during epiphany.
- Christmas elves. They make some presents, but they also help Santa to write messages and translate them.
- Windows. Simple as that, but it takes more time.
- The same way he knows if you are good or bad. His work with NSA, so he knows everything.
- He gives it to the reindeers, they need food with all exercise they do.